# History pushstate in Facebook App

Tags: facebook, sandbox, browser-history, history.js

I am using History.js for history management in my web app. Everything is working fine for all modern browsers when the app is being used directly on my website. All of these browsers except from IE9 also work fine when the app is being loaded from within the Facebook framework (as a Facebook app). With IE9 it seems that the pushstate method is unable to get the state added to the history.
I guess it has something to do with Facebook sandboxing the app. Since IE9 does not natively support HTML5 history methods, it makes use of URL hashtags. Is there any particular reason why this does not work in a Facebook app. And is there any solution to the problem?

Answer (score 1):

IE9 does not support PushState.  Check this out http://www.quora.com/Does-Internet-Explorer-9-support-pushState